# Show/Hide div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to show and hide a div based on a condition (for facebook in this example). 
Here is the code I am using, but for some reason, the alert works, but it still shows the div. 
Can someone help debug this. thanks.

```
    <?php
      // call the function to parse the signed request
$sr_data = mySignedRequest();

// check like status
if ($sr_data->page->liked==1) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">
        alert("Hello You Are a Fan");       
            document.getElementById("header").style.display = "block";
        </script>';
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">
        alert("You are not a fan");     
            document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
        </script>';
}

?>
<div id="header">

Hello You Are a Fan
</div><!-- #header -->
```

Comment: I think it would be much nicer if you wrote out your script tag like you are with your div down below and inside your script tag do something like `alert('<?php echo $sr_data->page-liked == 1 ? "Hello..." : "You are..."; ?>');`  It would save you a bunch of lines of code.  I know it wasn't the question but I'm just sayin ;)

Comment: or something more similar to what maxedison has below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typical example of code trying to access elements while they don't exist yet. You're namely fetching an element with `getElementById`, but the element is only defined *after* all JavaScript code.

You should use [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Moreover, jQuery has `.hide` and `.show` so you don't need `getElementById` and `style.display`:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">
    alert("Hello You Are a Fan");

    $(document).ready(function() { // only run when all elements are available
        $("#header").show();
    });
    </script>';
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because at the time the JS code runs, `#header` does not yet exist on the page. If you move the PHP (and therefore the JS) down below the #header div, it will work.

The better way to do it is to wrap the JS in a `$(document).ready()` call as pimvdb suggests.

HOWEVER, I don't think that will give you a good result because `#header` will actually be visible briefly, and then disappear. The best way to solve this specific case is to do something like:

```
<?php

if ($sr_data->page->liked==1) {
    $display = 'block';
} else {
    $display = 'none';
}

?>

<div id="header" style="display:<?php echo $display ?>">

Hello You Are a Fan
</div>
```

By embedding the correct style inline with the div, it will never show up when it shouldn't.

Comment: That works too. I can't check two things...I guess. Thanks for this alternative solution.

Comment: what 2 things can't you check?

Answer (score 1):

change code chunk order:html first

```
<div id="header">

Hello You Are a Fan
</div><!-- #header -->
<?php
      // call the function to parse the signed request
$sr_data = mySignedRequest();

// check like status
if ($sr_data->page->liked==1) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">
        alert("Hello You Are a Fan");       
            document.getElementById("header").style.display = "block";
        </script>';
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">
        alert("You are not a fan");     
            document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
        </script>';
}

?>
```

because when js runing,the #header dom is not exit.

Answer (score -1):

Change the document.getEle... to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#header").show();
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#header").show();
});
```

Comment: nope. as others have pointed out, `#header` doesn't exist yet.